# Java annotation to set a field to it's name

Tags: java, annotations

Is there any Java annotation that sets a field value to it's name, for example:

```
public interface Protocol {
    @Whatever String START; // Here @Whatever annotation would set START to "START" in any static string field.
}
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead to avoid typing: ` = "START"`

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to modify the way a class is compiled using annotations. You can generate *additional* classes based on the annotations or *handle* classes differently based on annotations, but you can't modify the class itself. [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) seems to be a counter-argument, but they pretty much hack the compiler (they don't and can't use the public APIs alone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, But you can use enum class.

```
public enum Protocol  {
   START,
   END
}
```

And then when you will write:

```
System.out.println(Protocol.START);
```

You will get "START"